# iOS Video Always in Portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I'm developing an App that uses **AVFoundation** for recording video.

Currently I've my video orientation set, when the Device Rotate it changes de video rotation

```
  [videoLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:currentOrientation];
```

But, when I play the video on Native Video Player it's shown on portrait, despite of being recorded on a landscape orientation.

Why this happens?
How I can fix this?

Thank you!